# Regular Expression python sql statements

Tags: python

I'm writing a regular expression code to extract items from a SQL statement.  I want to pull out a tuple of the items after `SELECT * FROM` and `WHERE` statements.

```
pattern = '''
    SELECT\s\*\sFROM\s ([a-zA-Z\s*\,*\=\.]+) \sWHERE \s*([a-zA-Z\d*\s*\,*\=*\.*]+)'''
```

From the pattern above, I'm using it for the SQL statement below, and get the following results:

```
('A, B, C\n           ', 'A.ColA = B.ColB AND B.ColB2=C.ColC')
```

I know it's because of the huge break before the `WHERE`, but how  do I factor that in and get rid of the huge space and `/n` after my first tuple?

```
q = """SELECT * FROM A, B, C
            WHERE A.ColA = B.ColB AND B.ColB2=C.ColC"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the returned result and use `re.sub`:

```
import re
results = ('A, B, C\n           ', 'A.ColA = B.ColB AND B.ColB2=C.ColC')
new_results = tuple(re.sub('\n\s+$', '', i) for i in results)
```

Output:

```
('A, B, C', 'A.ColA = B.ColB AND B.ColB2=C.ColC')
```

Or, you can alter your pattern:

```
import re
q = """SELECT * FROM A, B, C
        WHERE A.ColA = B.ColB AND B.ColB2=C.ColC"""
new_data = re.findall('(?<=SELECT \* FROM\s)[A-Z\s,]+(?=\n)|(?<=WHERE\s)[\w\W]+', q)
```

Output:

```
['A, B, C', 'A.ColA = B.ColB AND B.ColB2=C.ColC']
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the added approach of looping it over.  And also love the cleanliness of the pattern alternation

Comment: @GenXeral glad to help! Please accept the answer if it helped you. Thank you!